# Не запускается сервер 1С на Линукс

Tags: linux, 1с

Отказывается запускаться 1с сервер со словами "error: service failed to start! FAILED"

При попытке запуска программы пишет

> Connection refused line =1358 file=./src/DataExchangeTopClientlmpl.cpp (descr=111(0x0000006F))

Так же не работает интернет по подключению юсб модема, хоть графический интерфейс и пишет что подключение установлено но браузер пишет "problem occurred while loading the URL ... ". Хост пустой. В ifconfig аномалий нет..

Помогите найти сторону с которой подойти..

Comment: какой у вас дистрибутив ?

Comment: @icedev-sk Ubuntu

Comment: **s/Ubuntu/Debian/** - с этой стороны лучше подойти.